# Label text doesn't update on Windows form after adding 0 to it by type casting C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm making a simple calculator in windows form through C++.. I have a condition in which when i click 0 button after being in decimal part it should update label text on screen... but it doesn't .. forexample:

i have on screen
334.5
i click 0 button, it doesn't update on label
but when i click other button lets say 8 then it updates like this

334.508

I'm type casting from double type to string and vice versa...

here is a piece of code ...

```
    int totalLength = 0;
bool decimalPressed = false;
int decimalPart = 1;
bool isNegative = false;

void AddNewNum(double num){
    if (totalLength < 12){
        if (decimalPressed == false){
            if (isNegative == false){
                double prevDisplay = Convert::ToDouble(label1->Text);
                prevDisplay = (prevDisplay * 10) + num;
                label1->Text = Convert::ToString(prevDisplay);
            }
            else{
                double prevDisplay = -1 * Convert::ToDouble(label1->Text);
                prevDisplay = (prevDisplay * 10) + num;
                label1->Text = Convert::ToString(-1 * prevDisplay);
            }
        }
        else{// for adding digits in decimal part in this section error occurs .. only problem is display everything is okay
            if (isNegative == false){
                double prevDisplay = Convert::ToDouble(label1->Text);
                if (num != 0)
                    prevDisplay = ((prevDisplay * (pow(10, decimalPart)) + num) / pow(10, decimalPart));
                else{
                    prevDisplay = ((prevDisplay * (pow(10, decimalPart))) / pow(10, decimalPart));
                }
                label1->Text = Convert::ToString(prevDisplay);
            }
            else{
                double prevDisplay = -1 * Convert::ToDouble(label1->Text);
                prevDisplay = ((prevDisplay * (pow(10, decimalPart)) + num) / pow(10, decimalPart));
                if (num != 0)
                    prevDisplay = ((prevDisplay * (pow(10, decimalPart)) + num) / pow(10, decimalPart));
                else{
                    prevDisplay = ((prevDisplay * (pow(10, decimalPart))) / pow(10, decimalPart));
                }
                label1->Text = Convert::ToString(-1 * prevDisplay);
            }
            decimalPart++;
        }
        totalLength++;
    }
    else maskedTextBox1->Text = "LIMIT REACHED";
}
```

Comment: what are the types of `decimalPart` and how is it computed ? Please post a complete example.

Comment: it's int type..

Comment: I don't think you ought to call this "type casting".

Comment: hmm... but what's wrong here .. every calculation is going okay but it doesn't change on screen.. (label)

Comment: Maybe you can call `label1->Refresh()` to notify the modification to the graphical part.

Comment: Have you walked through this in a debugger? Did you step through "Convert::ToString" before and after adding the 0? Do you think that "334.5" and "334.50" are different numbers? Are "1" and "1.0" different numbers? What about "1" and "1.00000"?

Comment: `Convert::ToString` is likely where the issue is, and it's the code you didn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`334.5`, `334.50`, `334.50000000000`, these are all the same number to a `double`. You need to specify how many decimal places to display when formatting a `double` as a `string` with trailing zeros.

You should not be converting between `double` and `string` at all when you are just appending digits. Use simple string concatenation instead:

```
label1->Text = label1->Text + Convert::ToString(num);
```

Convert between `double` and `string` only when performing actual arithmetic operations, or if you want to validate the new string before assigning it, eg:

```
string s = label1->Text + Convert::ToString(num);
Convert::ToDouble(s); // check for errors
label1->Text = s;
```

Either way, there is no reason to keep track of any `decimalPart` value manually at all.  If the user enters a decimal, you can detect that so you can insert a `.` character when a subsequent digit is entered.

```
bool decimal = false;

...

// user enters decimal point...
decimal = true;

...

// user enters a digit...
string s = label1->Text;
if (decimal) {
    decimal = false;
    s = s + ".";
}
s = s + Convert::ToString(num);
Convert::ToDouble(s); // check for errors
label1->Text = s;
```